# Login to a website with two post forms and pass csrf token with python requests

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to setup an automated login to https://vsco.co/user/login for a personal project, however I am struggling with this. I have managed to do this with other modules, but can't seem to make it work with requests and I would much rather use it for my project.
Here are the forms:

```
vsco 
<POST https://vsco.co/user/doLogin application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(CsrfToken=mRoixL6/XRcqxoKftacjncexCkb8gSgE4yCrtWfi7ZI=) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(login=)>
  <PasswordControl(password=)>
  <SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
Form name: None
<POST https://vsco.co/user/doConsent application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(CsrfToken=mRoixL6/XRcqxoKftacjncexCkb8gSgE4yCrtWfi7ZI=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(key=) (readonly)>
  <RadioControl(consent=[confirm, reject])>
  <SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
>>>
```

Here is one basic snippet of the many different variations I have tried:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36' 
    }

data = {
    'login': 'user',
    'password': 'password'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.get("https://vsco.co/user/login")
s.post("https://vsco.co/user/doLogin", data=data, headers=headers)
```

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first use `DevTools` in Firefox / Chrome (tab: network) to see all traffic - and you will see it send `CsrfToken` and `tkn` - and you have to also send it in `data`. But you need `lxml` or `Beautifulsoup` to get values from HTML

Answer (score 0):

Hello i recommend you using Fiddler

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

turn on https decrypt and just follow all data u send. Also keep in mind that u need new csrf token for each request, so first has to be get to https://vsco.co/user/login then u have to reuse recieved csrf where u need it.